# Strip first part of string and return remaining string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to Javascript and couldn't find an answer to what I was looking to do. Here's what I have.

I'm getting a url from a page that is sometimes in the format of this: `http://url1.come/http://url2.com/dir/some/file.html`

What I'd like to do is strip the first part off (`http://urlhere.come/`) and return just the 2nd part which would be: `http://anotherUrlHere.com/dir/some/file.html`.

In order to be robust, I'd rather not specifically look for `url1.com` since that may change in the future. What will not change, however, is that there are two occurences of `http:` so I'd think that the best way would be to find the 2nd occurence of `http` and then strip off everything before that. I'm just now sure how.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
str = str.replace(/^http:\/\/.*http:\/\//, 'http://');
```

Comment: I recommend accounting for `https` links, just in case: `str.replace(/^https?:\/\/.*http(s?):\/\//, 'http$1://')`

Comment: Cool, thanks @Barmar. And, yes, Brian S, I should account for `https` as well, I agree. Thanks guys.

Comment: This works great, but I'm wondering if I can get an explanation of Brian S's answer. I looked at some javascript regex documentation but I can't see what the `$1` does. I know that the `$` matches the end of the line but I didn't see any documentation referring to a number after it. Thanks.

Comment: In the replacement string, `$N` matches the part of the input that matched the `Nth` capture group in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that Javascript `.replace()`, when not used with a regex, replaces just the first occurence of a substring, you could perform:

```
 //Assuming url = "http://url1.come/http://url2.com/dir/some/file.html"

 var result = url.replace("http://url1.come/", "");
```